# Question previews with MathJax render weirdly in search results

Tags: bug, search, user-interface, stackexchange-2.0, latex

I posted a similar [question](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/591/clumsy-view-of-well-formatted-questions-what-to-do) at [meta.chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/) and [Martin](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/4945/martin) suggested that I post it here. So here goes. [image]

This seems to be the issue only in our search page. The question that begins with "does resonance" is formatted by one of our moderators: "[ManishEarth](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/22/manishearth)"

Correct and thorough formatting was applied, and in the main page of the question you see no problems. But search pages seem to have an algorithm that misinterprets the dollar signs:

> ...now I am a little bit confused since I cannot figure out the resonance structure for...

Before and after the phrase above we have dollar signs that were used for the formatting of NO<sub>2</sub><sup>-</sup> and NO<sub>2</sub><sup>+</sup>.

So, what should we (more like, you) do about these questions? We (you) can't leave them like that, can we?!

Comment: Looks like mathjax is interpreting the excerpt.

Comment: Another MCVE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWFVi.png the [search](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12102+center+of+mass) and the [post itself](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34610/12102)